# How to change font color in Excel based on cell value?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2003

How do you change the font color of a column of cells based on their entered value? I've got a column with the heading at row 1 and the values starting at row 2 going on down. I want to change font color based on what is entered in the cells. E.g. If the value is Active, than make the color green and if it's Requested make it orange.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are looking for is conditional formatting.
[Here's a quick tutorial.](http://www.timeatlas.com/5_minute_tips/general/how_to_use_conditional_formatting_to_highlight_data)

Comment: Nice, that link is 100% what I needed. Thank you for your time and contribution!

Answer (score 8):

I'm adding an answer here that combines the **actual** steps from the tutorial that @JNK supplied, and updates for Excel 2013/2016 that @JohnDyer supplied in his comment.

You never know when one of Microsoft's links just stops working.

+1 @JNK

+1 @JohnDyer

**How to Apply Conditional Formatting**

To apply conditional formatting to one or more cells:

1. Highlight your cell or range of cells.
2. Select the *Conditional Formatting* button on the *Home* tab of the ribbon.
3. Select *Highlight Cell Rules*.
4. Select a cell evaluator from the second drop-down box.
5. Enter your values in the dialog that pops up.
6. Click the *OK* button.

Comment: If you're using Excel 2013 / 2016, conditional formatting is on the ribbon Home tab on the left side of the Styles box.  Select the column and then add a rule for each different color you need.

Comment: @JohnDyer this is a lifesaver, please add it as an answer in its own right.

Comment: @RegEdit +1 for your suggestion